# Como fazer upload de aquivos grandes para o google drive

Tags: python-3.x, upload, google, http-request, google-drive-api

Estou tentando fazer o upload de arquivos de *1-4Gb* para o **google drive**(*v3*) , usando **phyton3.8**, porém quando sempre tenho erros na execução:
*TypeError: 'PreparedRequest' object is not callable*

```
def uploaddearquivo(nome:str, caminho:str):
    size = os.path.getsize(caminho)
    access_token = "###"  
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json; charset:UTF-8","X-Upload-Content-Type":'application/octet-stream','X-Upload-Content-Length':str(size)}
    params = {
        "name": nome,
        "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
    }
    http = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(params)
    )


    file_metadata = {'name':nome}
    chunk = 10*(1024*256)
    fh = open(caminho,'rb',buffering=chunk)
    media = MediaIoBaseUpload(fh,chunksize=chunk,resumable=True,mimetype=FILESTYPE['default'])
    # media = MediaFileUpload(caminho,chunksize=chunk,resumable=True)
    file = DRIVECONTROLER.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media
    ).execute(http=http,num_retries=3)
    media.stream()
    response = None
    while response is None:
        status, response = file.next_chunk()
        if status:
            print ("Uploaded {}%".format(int(status.progress() * 100)))
    print("File ID: {}".format(file.get('id')))
```

no que estou errando?

*Em uploads menores não tenho problema utilizando apenas o* **MediaFileUpload**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema tava em um conflito entre a google-api-python-client e a httplib2.
foi resolvido com o downgrade dos mesmos

```
pip install httplib2==0.15.0

pip install google-api-python-client==1.6
```

link pra consulta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815620/gcloud-upload-httplib2-redirectmissinglocation-redirected-but-the-response-is-m